# Problems running two versions of ThinkingSphinx on the same server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I have a dedicated server set up with two instances of my app. One in production, one in staging

I can't seem to run Thinking Sphinx on both apps at the same time.

When I try to start it, I get this error:

`[Tue Jul 30 10:02:31.618 2013] [20464] Child process 20465 has been forked
[Tue Jul 30 10:02:31.669 2013] [20465] listening on 127.0.0.1:9306
[Tue Jul 30 10:02:31.669 2013] [20465] bind() failed on 127.0.0.1, retrying...
[Tue Jul 30 10:02:34.672 2013] [20465] bind() failed on 127.0.0.1, retrying...
[Tue Jul 30 10:02:37.676 2013] [20465] bind() failed on 127.0.0.1, retrying...
[Tue Jul 30 10:02:40.679 2013] [20465] bind() failed on 127.0.0.1, retrying...
[Tue Jul 30 10:02:43.682 2013] [20465] bind() failed on 127.0.0.1, retrying...
[Tue Jul 30 10:02:46.685 2013] [20465] bind() failed on 127.0.0.1, retrying...
[Tue Jul 30 10:02:49.688 2013] [20465] bind() failed on 127.0.0.1, retrying...
[Tue Jul 30 10:02:52.691 2013] [20465] bind() failed on 127.0.0.1, retrying...
[Tue Jul 30 10:02:55.694 2013] [20465] bind() failed on 127.0.0.1, retrying...
[Tue Jul 30 10:02:58.697 2013] [20465] bind() failed on 127.0.0.1, retrying...
[Tue Jul 30 10:03:01.700 2013] [20465] bind() failed on 127.0.0.1, retrying...
[Tue Jul 30 10:03:04.703 2013] [20465] bind() failed on 127.0.0.1, retrying...
[Tue Jul 30 10:03:07.706 2013] [20465] FATAL: bind() failed on 127.0.0.1: Address already in use
[Tue Jul 30 10:03:07.707 2013] [20464] Child process 20465 has been finished, exit code 1. Watchdog finishes also. Good bye!`

Can anyone advise how I can run TS on two versions of the same app on the same server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify different ports for different environments:

http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/advanced_config.html